# ios image thumbnailing for each device resolution

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiimage, uikit

So I cannot find any resources on how this works, 
I have 3 device resolutions 1x 2x and 3x.
Lets assume I an app that generates images of size 640 by 640.

If my uiimage is 64 by 64 points, that means that I have to provide 3 specific resolutions of that thumbnail.
So a 64by64 a 128by128 and and 192by192 ?

Meaning that I have to find a 192 by 192 image or larger than that and scale it down in some manner to ensure that it is properly rendered ? 
So I would take my 640 by 640 and scale it down to those 3 resolutions so they would be rendered correctly for each screen resolution ?

if someone can clarify this it would be great thank you!

Comment: You can use PDF vector: `http://martiancraft.com/blog/2014/09/vector-images-xcode6/` and Xcode will resize it for you

Comment: So I am right ? I need to scale images I am talking about pictures not image assets

Comment: If you decide to use PDF Vector, you need only one size, only one file.

Comment: Yes I understand that... but say my app is shooting pictures that are of size 640 by 640 in pixels ... as in the description, where I run this operation at run time not development time .... will I have to scale down the 640 by 640 image to those sizes at RUNTIME I am just gonna say yes to this.